# Does template <typename T> need to be declared for each template function?

Tags: c++, templates

For a class with multiple template functions does template have to be included in each declaration like so:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void foo(T a);

        template <typename T>
        void bar(T b);
}
```

Or can you just include `template <typename T>` for the first declaration like so:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void foo(T a);
        void bar(T b);
}
```

I suspect only the first one is valid since without the `;` it makes me think the declaration is actually `template <typename T> void foo(T a)` if written on one line. I assume its just convention to separate it into two lines! Looking for confirmation.

Comment: Correct. In your second example, `foo` is a template function, `bar` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `template` specifier must appear before each templated function. Your second example will cause an error that `T` is not a recognized type for `bar`, since `template <typename T>` applies only to `foo` in this case.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the same type for each function in a class, you could declare the entire class as a template:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void foo(T a);
    void bar(T b);
};
```